# Code of `pmalloc` in the book 'Programming Pearls'

Tags: c, malloc

I am a little confused when I look at solutions on this book:

```
#define NODESIZE 8
#define NODESGROUP 100
int leftnodes = 0;
char *freenode;
void *pmalloc(int size)
{
    void *p;
    if (size != NODESIZE)
        return malloc(size);
    if (leftnodes == 0)
    {
        freenode = malloc(NODESGROUP * NODESIZE);
        leftnodes = NODESGROUP;
    }
    leftnodes--;
    p = (void *)freenode;
    freenode = freenode + NODESIZE;
    return p;
}
```

The code above aims to `malloc` a block of space at once, and reduce the chances to use `malloc()` too much.

Why it needs to use `char *freenode` first and then change it into `void*`? Why not define it as `void * first`?

Comment: It has a memory leak for a start (assuming that it is a replacement for `malloc/free`)

Comment: Did you try to change `freenode` to `void*` and see what happens?

Comment: `freenode = freenode + NODESIZE;`, what would `+ NODESIZE` do if `freenode` was a `void*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not define `pnode` as `void*` first?

The answer to your question is on this line:

```
freenode = freenode + NODESIZE;
```

It perorms pointer arithmetic on `freenode`, which is prohibited on `void*`.

Recall that adding an integer `N` to a pointer adkusts the address by `sizeof(*pointer) * N`. When the pointer is `char *`, `sizeof(*pointer)` is equal to one, so the address is moved forward by `NODESIZE`. When the pointer is `void*`, `sizeof(*pointer)` is not defined, and a compile error results.

Comment: Is there anything special about NODESIZE, which in this book is 8.  I didn't find any explanation about it before.

Comment: @Jutta They picked `NODESIZE` to be pretty small so that the overhead of using `malloc` would be significant. Since `malloc` stores additional information for each allocation, allocating each block of 8 bytes could cost you 16 bytes of real memory, i.e. 100% overhead on top of what you need. If you use `NODESIZE` of, say, 80, then an 8-byte overhead would be only 10%, which is not nearly as impressive.

Comment: If I increase NODESIZE, will overhead be increased as well?

Comment: @Jutta No, if you increase `NODESIZE` the overhead will decrease. Overall overhead is measured as ratio of overhead bytes to total bytes. The amount added on top of the size you request is fixed (usually 4 to 8 bytes). If you ask for 8 bytes and the system allocates 8+8, the number of overhead bytes is equal to the number of payload bytes. If you ask for 800 bytes and get 808, the number of overhead bytes is 100 times less than the number of payload bytes.